# Access point and many repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater, mikrotik

I have TPLink eap 110 outdoor connected to mikrotik rb941 2nd hap lite which connected to ISP router. The speed is 50mbps shared for 8 users. They usually have 2 or 3 device so average about 18 active user at mikrotik hotspot

I create queue rules and 8 users and It was works fine. But these days it start to have huge lags and timeout. When trying to ping from device to access point it averages 300ms and 1000ms every 5 or 7 second.

The ap is repeated by 4 tenda repeater because of some house are too far.

The distance from device to ap is about 10 meters without nothing blocking.

Is it normal to have 300ms ping to access point? Or 4 repeater are issues too? Sometimes even its disconnect from the WiFi it self from device. Any suggestion to make this network better? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Repeaters are horrible and waste bandwidth.  What you ate describing us not great, but its likely a product of congestion (is not enough bandwidth/WiFi spectrum).

If you can eliminate the repeaters and replace them with a wired backbone and AP's you will likely have much better throughput. If that's not an option, can you use Ethernet over powerline for a backbone?

Trying to make sure you have non-overlapping frequencies as much as possible will help with WiFi utilization.  A while back (prior to 802.11ac being a thing) I used 2.4 gigs to communicate with clients and 5gig to communicate between router and AP.

I've.not used tends gear, but perceive it to be at the low end of the market. Replacing it with prosumer geat (like Ubiquiti) can make a massive difference. (I've not used Microtic, but I understand they are also prosumer)

Answer (score 1):

> The ap is repeated by 4 tenda repeater because of some house are too far.

This won't work, for the following reason: Assume you have devices A - B - C so that A and B can communicate, and B and C can communicate, but A and C cannot communicate.

In the WLAN protocol, multiple devices use the same frequency (channel). The WLAN protocol has an arbitration feature that detects when multiple devices are sending at the same time, and resolves this to one device. But if A and C cannot communicate, this protocol doesn't work.

Therefore, if A and C start sending at the same time, B cannot receive anything, because of interference. This means as soon as you produce serious traffic on your WLANs, communications will fail, leading to retransmits and even more traffic, with even more failures.

So get rid of your repeaters, and use a wired backbone instead.

Or, alternatively, if putting up a physical cable is out of the question, a wireless backbone on a **different frequency** with **directional antennas**, so you can cross the distance in one hop. But then simple repeaters won't do, you need to have WLAN-routers that are capable of sending and receiving on two frequencies at once, and those are rare and expensive. You can replace those with **two** routers, but you've to configure them correctly (and you'll probably need an open-source firmware like OpenWRT for that).

So a physical cable is the best solution if you don't know how to do that.